# React object of arrays how to set specific index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have a useState() object that looks like this:

```
  const [financeSummary, setFinanceSummary] = useState({
        discountRate: 10,
        financeRate: 10,
        reinvestRate: 10,
        inflationRate: 3,
        singleInvestment: new Array(11).fill(0),
        phasedInvestment: new Array(11).fill(0),
        financedInvestment: new Array(11).fill(0),
        outflowSubtotal: new Array(11).fill(0),
        outflowRebates: new Array(11).fill(0),
        energySavings: new Array(11).fill(0),
        maintenanceSavings: new Array(11).fill(0),
        inflowRebates: new Array(11).fill(0)
    })
```

I am rendering some of these arrays as a table of inputs:

```
<tr>
   <td>Single Investment</td>
   {financeSummary.singleInvestment.map((item, i) => (
   <td><input type='number' value={item} onChange={(e) => 
       setFinanceSummary({ ...financeSummary, singleInvestment[i]: e.target.valueAsNumber})} />
   </td>
))}
</tr>
```

I am unable to use 'singleInvestment[i]' (',' expected.) in order to target a specific index. Is there a way to accomplish this without using a helper function to create a new array?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a new array by mapping over the old one and picking out the correct index to modify:

```
setFinanceSummary({ 
  ...financeSummary, 
  singleInvestment: financeSummary.singleInvestment.map((el, index) => index === i ? e.target.valueAsNumber : el)
})
```

Comment: This is one of the cleanest solutions to this problem I have come across - nice work.

Answer (score 0):

you have to wrap the index in [ ] :

```
     {financeSummary.singleInvestment.map((item, i) => (
            <td>
                <input type='number' value={item} onChange={(e) =>
                    setFinanceSummary({ ...financeSummary, [item]:e.target.valueAsNumber })} />
            </td>
        ))}
```

and instead of `singleInvestment[i]` , you must just write `[item]:e.target.valueAsNumber`

since `item` = `financeSummary.singleInvestment[i]`

Comment: I feel like this should work, but it doesn't. I've tried a couple of variations of this as well.